# Testing a class was added or removed with karma for an angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to write some unit tests for an angularjs app using karma/jasmine.

The part I'm hung up on is testing that a class was successfully added/removed.

The function I am trying to test:

```
vm.toggleMenu = function toggleMenu(prev) {
  if(angular.element('menu').hasClass('hide')) {
    if(prev) {
      angular.element('#view').removeClass('col-md-8').addClass('col-md-12');
    } else {
      angular.element('menu').removeClass('hide');
      angular.element('#view').removeClass('col-md-12').addClass('col-md-8');
    }
  } else {
    if(prev) {
      angular.element('#view').removeClass('col-md-12').addClass('col-md-8');
    } else {
      angular.element('menu').addClass('hide');
      angular.element('#view').removeClass('col-md-8').addClass('col-md-12');
    }
  }
};
```

the html:

```
<div id="view" class="col-md-12" ng-view=""></div>
<menu class="col-md-4"></menu>
```

menu is a custom directive.

my test:

```
describe('Ctrl spec', function() {
 var controller, vm, scope, menu, compile, view;



 beforeEach(function(){

  module('app');
  module('templates');

  inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $compile) {
    controller = $controller;
    scope = $rootScope;
    compile = $compile;
    vm = controller('Ctrl', {$scope: scope});
    menu = angular.element('<menu></menu>');
    view = angular.element('<div id="view" class="col-md-12"></div>');
    compile(menu)(scope);

    spyOn(vm, 'toggleMenu');
  })
});

describe('function', function() {

 it('view should have class col-md-8', function() {

   vm.toggleMenu();

   expect(view.hasClass('col-md-8')).toBe(true);
 });
});
```

when I console.log view I get

```
LOG: {0: <div id="view" class="col-md-12 ng-scope"></div>, length: 1}
```

I've also tried adding class ng-hide to the menu as so in my test-spec.js:

```
menu = angular.element('<menu class="hide"></menu>');
```

And always just get this as the output:

```
Expected false to be true.
Error: Expected false to be true.
```

Any help on how to properly test class was added/removed successfully would be appreciated!!

Comment: You shouldn't be using jqLite inside an Angular controller. Have you tried to use `ngClass`?

Comment: Would you confirm that the line of `addClass('col-md-8')` actually called?

Comment: Because I was updating elements not within the scope of this particular controller I didn't think I could use ng-class or ng-show. However I have since read more, and abstracted some logic into a service that could then let multiple controllers know about the change. So now using ng-class and ng-show I've changed how this test needed set up. However I also figured out there was a line in my controller `angular.element('menu').addClass('hide');` that was being called when the controller loaded, making the test not run properly. all angular.element lines have been removed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still couldn't let this go, so had to play with it more. I found my error.

This line: `menu = angular.element('<menu></menu>');` was being used wrong.

It needed to be `menu = angular.element('menu');`.

Angular.element is not meant to be used with the full tag, but with classes, ID's, or the name of the element itself.